# String to int in Java

Tags: java

I have a string named string1 that I read from a file. It's actually a number that I'm reading from the file. I now need to use that number in a random number generator. How can I do that?

```
String string1 = in.readLine();
Random generator = new Random();
int x = generator.nextInt(string1);
```

That obviously fails but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `int int1 = Integer.parseInt(string1);`.  Just make sure you do some error handling around that in case it is not an integer!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Integer.parseInt(String s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29):

```
int max = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
Random generator = new Random();
int x = generator.nextInt(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int num = Integer.valueOf(stringtext).intValue();
```

Next time google it.

Comment: But if everyone did that, there would hardly be a reason for this site to exist. See how that works? This is a question/answer forum.

Comment: yeah but this is very very simple question :) I guess

Comment: try this :) http://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&sa=X&ei=jQLETbS9N4mqrAfdnYzDBA&ved=0CBYQvwUoAQ&q=convert+String+to+int+java&spell=1&biw=1366&bih=677 a very simple query

Comment: @JJD I disagree. This site would not disappear if everyone googled for their answers first.  Instead, the ratio of interesting/challenging questions to cruft would dramatically increase.